Primary Key data type suggestion for MySQL for an application that depends in a external system. unsigned bigint vs varchar data type in primary keys
I'll give you some context and then ask my question.
I'm building a database model for an ecommerce application. This application needs to communicate to another system (ERP system) to get product, brands, categories and another information that is relevant to the ecommerce.
Currently, the ecommerce database model is designed identical to the data types that the external system offer.
I'll share to you some of the ecommerce tables:
aikon_articulo
CREATE TABLE `aikon_articulo` (
  `aik_ar_codigo` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_publicarweb` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `aik_ar_descri` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_memo` varchar(4000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_alto` double NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_ancho` double NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_profundo` double NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_color` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_peso` double NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_descria` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_mesesgarantia` double NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_cosnet` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `aik_ap_utilidad` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `aik_ap_impuesto_interno` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `aik_iva_porcen` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `aik_stock_total` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `aik_ap_precio_iva` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `aik_ar_fechamodif` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `aik_ar_fecha_alta` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `aik_fa_codigo` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_ma_codigo` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_re1_codigo` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_re2_codigo` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_esa_codigo` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aik_ar_codigo`),
  KEY `aikon_articulo_aik_fa_codigo_fkey` (`aik_fa_codigo`),
  KEY `aikon_articulo_aik_ma_codigo_fkey` (`aik_ma_codigo`),
  KEY `aikon_articulo_aik_re1_codigo_fkey` (`aik_re1_codigo`),
  KEY `aikon_articulo_aik_re2_codigo_fkey` (`aik_re2_codigo`),
  KEY `aikon_articulo_aik_esa_codigo_fkey` (`aik_esa_codigo`),
  CONSTRAINT `aikon_articulo_aik_esa_codigo_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`aik_esa_codigo`) REFERENCES `aikon_estado_articulo` (`aik_esa_codigo`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `aikon_articulo_aik_fa_codigo_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`aik_fa_codigo`) REFERENCES `aikon_familia` (`aik_fa_codigo`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `aikon_articulo_aik_ma_codigo_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`aik_ma_codigo`) REFERENCES `aikon_marca` (`aik_ma_codigo`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `aikon_articulo_aik_re1_codigo_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`aik_re1_codigo`) REFERENCES `aikon_referencia01` (`aik_re1_codigo`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `aikon_articulo_aik_re2_codigo_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`aik_re2_codigo`) REFERENCES `aikon_referencia02` (`aik_re2_codigo`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

aikon_estado_articulo
CREATE TABLE `aikon_estado_articulo` (
  `aik_esa_codigo` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_esa_descri` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aik_esa_codigo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

aikon_marca
CREATE TABLE `aikon_marca` (
  `aik_ma_codigo` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aik_ma_descri` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aik_ma_codigo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

I just want you to pay special attention to the data types that the primary key has in each table. They're all string with different length. That's the external system has patterns in the values of the primary keys, depending on the table.
Aside for that, I've heard that the best data types for primary keys are unsigned bigint. I'm worried about if keeping string data types for each primary key is a good idea or not.
Should I leave data types as is, or I should change primary key's data types to unsigned bigint?
I don't actually know how much this database could grow, but I don't want to have surprises in the future like not being able to INSERT because we ran out of id's values.  This database is currently in the development phase, so, there is no problem in changing the schemas.

If the keys come from an external system that you have no control over, then you can't depend on them being numerical values at all, right? I mean two months from now, they could decide to use "AA8675309" as their id format, and then a BIGINT wouldn't work at all.
You also can't anticipate whether they will change the length of the id values in the future. So varchar(24) might be too short someday for the data you receive from the ERP system.
Ultimately, you can't predict the future.
Design the system to handle the format you know is in use today, and set expectations with your employer that if these assumptions change, you'll have to make alterations to handle new data formats.

As you say, I cannot control keys coming from the external application, and it may change the format in the future. Currently, those keys are used as primary keys in my database. I was thinking that maybe, I could define a primary key unsigned bitint with autoincremental and set the external system key as a secondary key and also making it unique in my database. Is that a good approach? Keeping external system keys as primary keys in my database could give me problems if they change for some reason. What do you think on the approach that I'm thinking?

I would keep the ERP key as the primary key, assuming you can rely on that key being unique. I don't see how adding the auto-increment key for your database helps the problem of anticipating changes in the ERP system.
